# Add and update without replicate empty elements - jQuery/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

For study purposes, I created a simple application that basically adds a value to the database via `$.post` and returns the result updated at the same time with JSON.

The big problem is that when adding and updating, are updated with empty elements. Example: If I already have 5 items added, when add one more item, it refreshes and returns the 5 items that were already have, plus 5 empty items and one item to the end with the value sent.

Below is the code that is sent for jQuery:

```
send_btn.bind('click', function () {

    var that = $(this),
        input_val = input_word.find('input').val();

    that.find('.wrp').css('margin-left', -152);

    $.post('post.php', { palavra: input_val }, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        that.find('.wrp').css('margin-left', 0);
        update();
    });

});
```

Below is the PHP file that receives the information: `post.php`

```
$_palavra = $_POST['palavra'];
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `glaubersampaio`.`postit` (`ID`, `PALAVRA`, `MOSTRAR`) VALUES (NULL, '".$_palavra."', '1');");
```

`update()` Function:

```
function update() {
    $.getJSON('request.php', function (data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $('<li class="postit" id="postit-' + data[i].id + '"></li>').appendTo(quadro.find('ul'));
            $('#postit-' + data[i].id).html('<h4>' + data[i].palavra + '</h4>');
            $('<div class="remover">REMOVER?</div>').appendTo('#postit-' + data[i].id);

        }
    })
        .done(function () {
        quadro.find('.loader').hide();
    });
}
```

The PHP file that makes the requisition: `request.php`

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `postit`");
$dados = array();

while($a = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    $ID = $a['ID'];
    $PALAVRA = $a['PALAVRA'];
    $MOSTRAR = $a['MOSTRAR'];

    array_push($dados, array("id"=>$ID, "palavra"=>$PALAVRA, "mostrar"=>$MOSTRAR));

}

echo json_encode($dados);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your `update()` function. Say you already have 5 items in your list, then you add a new one, it is saved in the database, then update() is called where you query ALL the data from your table, so your JSON response includes your previous 5 items plus the new item, now you loop through all of them and APPEND them to your list, append means they are added after the last element, so your original 5 plus the 5 in your query and your new item is the result you see in your table.

Why are the new 5 empty? because you use this line to create a new item:

```
$('<li class="postit" id="postit-' + data[i].id + '"></li>')
```

but you already had an item with that id, so invalid HTML markup is being generated and when you try to set the content here:

```
$('#postit-' + data[i].id).html('<h4>' + data[i].palavra + '</h4>');
```

Only the first element with the Id will be modified.

What would be the solution? You have a couple of options. The first would be to empty your list before adding the elements from your request query, so you clear your current items and repopulate the complete table from your query data.

```
$.getJSON('request.php', function (data) {
    quadro.find('ul').empty();
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('<li class="postit" id="postit-' + data[i].id + '"></li>').appendTo(quadro.find('ul'));
        $('#postit-' + data[i].id).html('<h4>' + data[i].palavra + '</h4>');
        $('<div class="remover">REMOVER?</div>').appendTo('#postit-' + data[i].id);
    }
})
```

But a more efficient approach would be to somehow get a reference of the oldest id that is in your table and send it to `request.php` to return only elements with an id greater than that. Something like

`update()` function

```
var lastID = 0;
function update() {
    $.getJSON('request.php', {lastID: lastID}, function (data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            //apend element
            if(i == data.length-1)
                lastID = data[i].id;
        }
    });
}
```

And in `request.php`

```
$lastID = isset($_POST['lastID']): $_POST['lastID'] : 0;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `postit` WHERE ID > $lastID ORDER BY ID ASC");
```